# Among/Between the four of them

Tags: prepositions

Can "between" be replaced by "among" in the following?

> Between the four of them they managed to lift her into the ambulance.

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam-Webster, **[between](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between)**, the first meaning is

> 1a: by the common action of
> : jointly engaging

This is the appropriate meaning for a group of people collaborating to achieve an objective.

Looking at **[among](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/among)**, we get to meaning 6b before we get anything similar:

> 6b: through the joint action of

though the example isn't in my opinion, very collaborative:

> made a fortune among themselves

According to the dictionary, then, you could in principle replace **between** by **among** in your sentence, but I feel that **among** has a more of a divisive feel, which isn't really compatible with working together to achieve an objective.

Answer (score 0):

Some people subscribe to a prescriptive rule that "between" is appropriate only for a group of two, and "among" should be used for a group of three or more.

In practice, "between" is sometimes used for groups larger than two. And it may be preferable to "among" for the expression "___ the (number) of them" when it refers to combining resources toward a common goal. [Google n-gram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=between+the+three+of+them%2Cbetween+the+four+of+them%2Camong+the+three+of+them%2Camong+the+four+of+them&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbetween%20the%20three%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbetween%20the%20four%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camong%20the%20three%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camong%20the%20four%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbetween%20the%20three%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbetween%20the%20four%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camong%20the%20three%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camong%20the%20four%20of%20them%3B%2Cc0)

I would probably not change the original sentence.